# jQuery $('input :selected').val() returns undefined

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-input

I know this is probably a stupid question, but I can't find the answer anywhere.

When I try to run this code:

```js
$(() => {
    $("input.search").on('keyup', () => {
        console.log($("input.search :selected").val());
    });
});
```

```html
<head>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js'
        integrity='sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg=='
        crossorigin='anonymous'></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form class="search">
      <input type="text" class="search" placeholder="Search..." name="search">
  </form>
</body>
```

The line $("input.search :selected").val() returns null. Why is this, and how do I fix it?
Thanks so much!

Comment: remove the space

Comment: Try removing the space from the selector as that indicates to search for a child element, `input.search:selected`. Note though you could just include the event object and get the element triggering the event from that, ie `(e)=>{ console.log(e.target.value); }` instead of doing another lookup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [selected-selector](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) `selected` works with `options`. In your case you could have used `$(this)` but since you are using fat function the scope of `this` will be different So use the event object to get the value

```js
$(() => {
  $("input.search").on('keyup', (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js' integrity='sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form class="search">
    <input type="text" class="search" placeholder="Search..." name="search">
  </form>
```